# Facing an issue of double sound on Google chrome while running Edge animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I have created an animation in Adobe Edge animate itself and its working fine on the browser. Next thing I have added a voice over to the animation which is completely synced and running perfectly using j-query.

Here's the problem which i am facing - while running the animation on the Google Chrome and Safari, I am getting double sound which is annoying. I have discovered on internet that Google chrome supports MP3, OGG, WAV formats for the audio. And Mozilla supports the OGG format. I have connected the two formats with animation using j-query which are MP3 and OGG format. And Google Chrome is reading the both formats which is creating an issue.

Please help me out to remove the double sound issue in Chrome.

Regards
Vikas Sharma

Comment: provide a code, fiddle is best

Comment: I've had it happen reliably when using the Web Audio API and using an `<audio>` element as the source.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using an `<audio>` tag, you might try using the html5 audio object and manipulating it with javascript.

here's an example:

```
var audiophile = new Audio();
audiophile.src = 'audiofile.mp3';
audiophile.play();
```

that way you're only referencing one source file, and there's no chance of two playing simultaneously.

hope this helps.